# Is there a way to view the contents of localStorage on the iPad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, local-storage

In Settings/Safari, there is a Databases entry that allows me to view databases that have been created on my iPad (not their contents, but their size and origin).

However, I don't see any way to see what's in localStorage. I'm using the console to access localStorage in Safari (Develop > Show Web Inspector and clicking on the Storage tab).

Is there a way to view localStorage on the iPad that I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have access to an Apple computer, you can use Safari's Web Inspector to inspect stuff on your iPad - including localStorage and sessionStorage.

- In your iPad, go to `Settings` > `Safari` > `Advanced` and turn on `Allow Remote Debugging`.
- Then, plug it into your Apple computer.
- In Safari, go to your settings and choose `Advanced`. Check the box that says `Show Develop menu in the menu bar`.
- Now, if you click on `develop` on the top menu bar, you will be able to see your iPad. You will be able to inspect elements and use it much like Webkit's Web Inspector.

Currently, though, it is not using the standard Webkit inspector - and [many people](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4158378?start=0&tstart=0) [have an issue](http://undefinedbehavior.net/2012/08/08/safari-6-webkit-inspector-mess/) [with this.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58691/how-to-revert-safari-6-web-inspector)

Answer (score 1):

You can access localStorage with javascript commands.  (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#localStorage for reference.)

To debug remotely, try using http://jsconsole.com/.

Also, you can enable viewing of console.log() output under iPad Settings -> Safari, which might help you debug locally.

Comment: So no way to do it other than through the console sounds like.  Thanks!