# error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.location.Location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-geolocation

I am retrieving the location of a device by using WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(onGeoLocationSuccess, onGeoLocationFailure, options), provided by MobileFirst.

The first time is works fine. I get the location and everything is ok.

However, at a point in the application I clear the localStorage. When I do so, the app goes crazy and I keep getting this error in the console:

```
getPosition - error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.location.Location com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLGPSListener.getLastKnownLocation()' on a null object reference
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
position();

function position() {

  var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy : false,
    timeout            : 20000,
    maximumAge         : 30000,
    highAccuracyOptions: {
      desiredAccuracy: 50, //meters
      iOSBestAccuracy: WL.Device.Geo.IOS_BEST_ACCURACY
    }
  };

  WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(onGeoLocationSuccess, onGeoLocationFailure, options);
}

function onGeoLocationSuccess(position) {
  WL.Logger.info('Got position now ;)');
}

function onGeoLocationFailure(errorObj) {
  console.log('Trying again ');
  position();
}
```

This is how I am resetting the localStorage in another service

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check for the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873145/is-there-a-way-to-view-the-contents-of-localstorage-on-the-ipad) of the localStorage; Since you are force-clearing the entire storage, I suspect you are clearing required data during an application's runtime.

Only clear what you need clearing, not all of it.